# Trying to get property '' of non-object (View:

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to fetch a user based on their corresponding District/ area by the ID stored in the user table,

I am able to fetch the result for District where as for the Area, I am getting error,

> Trying to get property 'area_name' of non-object (View:
>   user-index.blade.php)

```
User 

id | district_id | area_id | user_name

District

id | district_name

area

id | district_id | area_name
```

**Controller**

```
 $users = Users::simplePaginate(5);

        return view('user-index',compact('users'));
```

**Model**

User

```
public function districts(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Districts','district_id','id');
    }

    public function areas(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Area','area_id','id');
    }
```

**blade**

```
 @foreach ($users as $user)
                              {{$user-> first_name}}  -  I get result
                              {{$user->districts->district_name}} - I get result
                              {{$user->areas->area_name}} -- I get error 

@endforeach
```

Comment: What does `dd($users)` show? Show us your Area model.

Comment: its fetching me the results in the users table @Script47

Comment: Try to print a single $user using `dd()`.

Comment: please post dd($users) output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this** in your controller:

```
$users = Users::with('areas')->with('districts')->simplePaginate(5);
return view('user-index',compact('users'));
```

**Edit Answer:**

In **User** Model:

```
public function districts() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Districts','district_id','id');
}
```

In **District** Model:

```
public function areas() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Area','district_id','id');
}
```

And In you **Controller**, you will fetch the relation like this:

```
$users = Users::with('districts.areas')->simplePaginate(5);
return view('user-index',compact('users'));
```

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: Still same error, Cleared cache(app,view,route) too

Comment: @mightyteja I edited my answer now try this solution.

Comment: This also works, I have a question here. Just in case if there is area id in user, how would I show an error

Comment: The answer of your question is so simple, in your case the area is dependent on the district so the relation define between the district with area not the user with area........ 
 The `User` belongs to `District` belongs to `Area`....... This is the correct relation.

Answer (score 2):

Error occurs becouse same user does not have area. For fix it use this

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    {{$user->first_name}}
    {{$user->districts->district_name ?? ''}}
    {{$user->areas->area_name ?? ''}} 
@endforeach
```

or

```
@foreach ($users as $user)

    {{$user-> first_name}}

    @if($user->districts)
        {{$user->districts->district_name}}
    @endif

    @if($user->areas)
        {{$user->areas->area_name}}
    @endif

@endforeach
```

Also for belongs to relations use singulare name

```
public function district(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Districts','district_id','id');
}

public function area(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Area','area_id','id');
}
```

That case in blade use

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    {{$user->first_name}}
    {{$user->district->district_name ?? ''}}
    {{$user->area->area_name ?? ''}} 
@endforeach
```

And for avoid lazy loading in controller use

```
$users = Users::with(['area', 'district'])->simplePaginate(5);
return view('user-index',compact('users'));
```

Comment: Thanks Davit, it worked out :) . I have a question here. Just in case if there is area id in user is not in the area, how would I show an error –

Comment: Could you please highlight

Comment: `$users = Users::with('area')->with('district')->simplePaginate(5);` if you change relation name else `$users = Users::with('areas')->with('districts')->simplePaginate(5);`

Comment: I just update it to $users = Users::simplePaginate(5);. Its working. Do I fix the issue??

Comment: When you use `Users::simplePaginate(5);` That case in db query must be executed 11 time. but when you use `$users = Users::with('areas')->with('districts')->simplePaginate(5);` must be executed 3 times

Comment: Haah Thank you,will update back to  $users = Users::with('areas')->with('districts')->simplePaginate(5);

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading see more detailed

Answer (score 2):

Try in your controller

```
$users = Users::with(['areas','districts'])->simplePaginate(5);
return view('user-index',compact('users'));
```

In your blade file check relationship is set or not.

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
   {{ $user->first_name }}
   {{ $user->districts ? $user->districts->district_name : '' }}
   {{ $user->areas ? $user->areas->area_name : '' }} 
@endforeach
```